# How to test if my linq query went through

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

This is my code from my controller:

```
MGEntities db = new MGEntities();
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Attempt to register the user
            MembershipCreateStatus createStatus = MembershipService.CreateUser(model.UserName, model.Password, model.Email);

            if (createStatus == MembershipCreateStatus.Success)
            {

                FormsService.SignIn(model.UserName, false /* createPersistentCookie */);
                MembershipUser myObject = Membership.GetUser();
                Guid UserID = (Guid)myObject.ProviderUserKey;

                MyProfile profile = new MyProfile();
                profile.Address = model.Address;
                profile.City = model.City;
                profile.Zip = model.Zip;
                profile.State = model.State;
                profile.UserId = UserID;

                Debug.Write(profile.State);

                db.aspnet_Profiles.Add(profile);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", AccountValidation.ErrorCodeToString(createStatus));
            }
        }
```

This is my MyProfile Class:

```
namespace MatchGaming.Models
{
    [Bind(Exclude = "ProfileId")]
    public class MyProfile
    {
        [Key]
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public int ProfileId { get; set; }

        public Guid UserId { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Address")]
        public string Address { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("City")]
        public string City { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Zip")]
    public string Zip { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("State")]


     public string State { get; set; }
}
}
```

After the linq query is executed, i check my database and nothing is added.  I am using POCO for my entities. Here is my class:

```
namespace MatchGaming.Models
{
    public class MGEntities : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<MyProfile> aspnet_Profiles { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I basically just dont understand why its not adding to the database, if theres a way I can check if the query went through correctly or not or if anyone can see the problem.  Thank you!

Comment: Yes, I debugged and got no errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
db.aspnet_Profiles.Add(profile);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

You're misusing EF.

EF contexts are not thread safe and cannot be reused across requests.
You need to create a separate context (`MGEntities`) for each request, by creating it in the controller in a `using` statement.

You also need to call `SaveChanges()`.

Comment: @anthin: `using(var db = new MGEntities()) { ... }`

Comment: I tried this, still no luck its not inserting into the database at all nor is it giving me any error.  Maybe im not connected properly to my database?